# How to get text from a web element

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am using this simple method to get the text of that element but does not work.
I am expecting to get something like "Total shipment weight:0kg"

**it prints out "#" why?**
    shipmentLane.totalShipmentWeight().getText();

Above method gives me: #3 !!

[image]

Comment: What kind of element is that?

Comment: Please take a look at the picture I recently uploaded

Comment: And how do you get the `shipmentLane.totalShipmentWeight()`? Show us the code.